# Angular extending ui.bootstrap.progressbar to support some text on the progressbar

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-bootstrap

I'm using [ui.bootstrap.progressbar](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/progressbar) (code here: https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/src/progressbar/progressbar.js) and I'm trying to extend it to support some custom HTML (or just text) on the progess bar. It looks something like this in vanilla Bootstrap:

```
   <div class="progress">
      <div class="bar" style="width: 60%;">This thing is at 60%</div>
    </div>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/WURPlkA0y6CK7HYt3GL1?p=preview

I'm new at directives, so I this is what I tried:

in `ProgressBarController` I added a `label` variable

`var label = angular.isDefined($attrs.label) ? $scope.$eval($attrs.label) : '';`

also modified the object the controller returns to include the label. Then added the `bar.label` in the directive's template like so:

```
<div class="progress">
    <progressbar ng-repeat="bar in bars" 
                 width="bar.to" old="bar.from" 
                 animate="bar.animate" type="bar.type">
    </progressbar>
    {{bar.label}}
 </div>
```

The progressbar appears just fine, but I cannot see the value of the label.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you paste the code of the directive you wrote?

Comment: Sorry, I was AFK. Modified the question with the code in question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be pretty straightforward.

All I had to do was:

- modify the `progress` directive and add `transclude: true`
- modify the `progress.html` to include an `ng-transclude` directive, like so

:

```
<div class="progress">
    <span ng-transclude></span>
    <progressbar ng-repeat="bar in bars" width="bar.to" old="bar.from" animate="bar.animate" type="bar.type"></progressbar>
</div>
```

After this, text put between the `<progressbar></progressbar>` will render on the progressbar, however some CSS modifications are also needed to make the text appear in the correct position.

But every progressbar and every text needs additional positioning, so this part is still not a complete solution. Setting the wrapper's position to relative and the `<span>`'s to absolute is one step but still not enough.